# Bash completion after redirection symbol

Tags: bash, bash-completion

When I try to complete a path after a redirect symbol, bash completion behaves as though it is still trying to complete arguments to the command before the redirect.

For example:
   `dpkg -l > /med`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

By hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `/med` I would expect it to complete the path to `/media/`, but instead it does nothing.

Is there a setting that I can change to make this work as I expect it to?
I am using the bash shell as provided by Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to invoke `complete-filename` instead of the "smart" completion.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, having Alt-/ bound to anything other than `dabbrev-expand` would drive me nuts. However I have learned from your suggestion and bound `complete-filename` to Shift-Tab.

Comment: Documentation here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Commands-For-Completion